# automatically insert random value in column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to generate random number of 6 digit in mysql.

For example,

I have a table named as **DATA** and columns are **job_name** and **job_id**.
So, when user insert value in **job_name** and the value of **job_id** which would be **random** and **unique** number which will be stored in database automatically.

I have been searched for this but can not get anything out of it. So, Please specify your answer in brief.

Comment: make `job_id` primary key and do `AUTO_INCREMENT` to start from 100000.

Comment: I agree with Jester, the solution yo have provided is not for random numbers

Comment: you need job_id to be a random number or another column in your db ,with a 6 digit random number?

Comment: No, I want job_id to be random and unique

Comment: why do you want it to be random?

Comment: Create random number using php and put it in db.

`function randomkey( $length ) {
    $chars = "0123456789";
    return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length);
}`

You can also make it more unique by adding current timestamp.

like `$key = randomkey(10) . date('dmYHis');`

Answer (score 1):

Give job_id the primary key and use Auto Increment in your database.
This way you just have to insert job_name and it will auto_increment the name by itself. [Auto Increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

P.S. this is not random, but there shouldn't really be a reason for it to be random? otherwise you'd have to make a script that keeps making random numbers and comparing them to the database until one doesn't exist yet.

If you really want it to be random check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353166/php-mysql-generating-unique-random-number)

I really suggest that you don't do this, there might also be a day where you run out of ids and it will get stuck in an endless loop if you limit it to 6 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 fields in your table. One is your `AUTO_INCREMENT` job_id and another new field: `job_unique_id`.
You can insert unique random values in that column using mysql `UUID` function. From your tags it seems like you're using codeigniter. In codeigniter use the following code for generating unique tokens:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'full name'
);
$this->db->set('job_unique_id', 'UUID()', FALSE);
$this->db->insert('my_table',$data);
```

Check this link for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Comment: Yup, I got it. but an you describe where should i put this code                   $this->db->set('job_unique_id', 'UUID()', FALSE);

Comment: `UUID` is in format `6ccd780c-baba-1026-9564-0040f4311e29` which is not 6 digits random integer

Comment: @DharaVihol - you need to add the code before the insert function.

Comment: No, It is not adding the random key, every time it is adding only zero.

Comment: The `job_unique_id` field needs to be of type `varchar(50)` or text. Also note the generated key looks like: '2787e8b8-1a60-11e5-be60-3085a9ad784a'. Check this link for more info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
INSERT INTO `DATA`(`job_id`, `job_name`) VALUES (ROUND((RAND() * (999999-100000))+100000),'php developer')
```

Comment: Can i see your table structure? As its working in my phpmyadmin when i query directly.